# Consumer example for Google Pub/Sub in C++

Tags: c++, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to play around Google Pub/Sub and I need to integrate it in C++ code-base.

As there is no native support for `Google Pub/Sub` in C++, I am using it through `gRPC`. Thus, I have generated corresponding `pubsub.grpc.pb.h`, `pubsub.grpc.pb.cc`, `pubsub.pb.h` and `pubsub.pb.cc` files via `protoc`.

Question part: because of lack of documentation it would be very helpful to have an example in C++. I have found an [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-pubsub-discuss/BE7A5qFqywQ) for publisher part, but not for the subscriber part. I tried to dive into the generated code and examples in other languages, but quite many question arise. Is there any example for the subscriber part? Or may be someone already had such kind of experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you are making Publish requests, you can make [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull) requests for messages. Note that this is a simple proof of concept, and, in practice, you’d probably want to make this code more robust; e.g. create multiple streams, have the message processing happen on a thread pool, implement some kind of flow control, etc…

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>

#include "google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.grpc.pb.h"

auto main() -> int {
    using grpc::ClientContext;
    using grpc::ClientReaderWriter;
    using google::pubsub::v1::Subscriber;
    using google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest;
    using google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullResponse;

    auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
    auto stub = std::make_unique<Subscriber::Stub>(
        grpc::CreateChannel("pubsub.googleapis.com", creds));

    // Open up the stream.
    ClientContext context;
    std::unique_ptr<ClientReaderWriter<
        StreamingPullRequest, StreamingPullResponse>> stream(
            stub->StreamingPull(&context));

    // Send initial message.
    StreamingPullRequest request;
    request.set_subscription(
        "projects/pubsub-cpp-api-1504713535863/subscriptions/testing");
    request.set_stream_ack_deadline_seconds(10);
    stream->Write(request);

    // Receive messages.
    StreamingPullResponse response;
    while (stream->Read(&response)) {
      // Ack messages.
      StreamingPullRequest ack_request;
      for (const auto &message : response.received_messages()) {
        ack_request.add_ack_ids(message.ack_id());
      }
      stream->Write(ack_request);
    }
}
```

This is the newest Cloud Pub/Sub API, and is the currently recommended way of pulling messages from the service; this is especially true for users who expect high throughput and low latency. Currently, there is no existing client library for C++, but there is an open [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/777) on GitHub for it. The existing client libraries for other languages (e.g. Java) already use this API, so you may be able to replicate their functionality in your own C++ code.

For simpler use-cases, you could also use the older [Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) API, which makes many independent requests for messages. Note that, for high throughput and low latency, you should most likely be making many simultaneous asynchronous RPCs: see gRPC [documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>

#include "google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.grpc.pb.h"

auto main() -> int {
    using grpc::ClientContext;
    using google::pubsub::v1::Subscriber;
    using google::pubsub::v1::PullRequest;
    using google::pubsub::v1::PullResponse;

    auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
    auto stub = std::make_unique<Subscriber::Stub>(
        grpc::CreateChannel("pubsub.googleapis.com", creds));

    PullRequest request;
    request.set_subscription(
        "projects/pubsub-cpp-api-1504713535863/subscriptions/testing");
    request.set_max_messages(50);
    request.set_return_immediately(false);

    PullResponse response;
    ClientContext ctx;

    auto status = stub->Pull(&ctx, request, &response);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        // ...
    }

    // Do something with "response".
}
```

As a last resort, you could use a [Push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) subscription, which would only require you to implement an HTTP endpoint on your client. However, this is not usually recommended unless you are fanning in from multiple subscriptions, or for cases where your client cannot make outgoing requests.

Comment: I used the first approach and it was working quite well. However, I encountered an issue lately. Could you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569932/deadlock-inside-grpc-read-function

Answer (score 0):

There is c++ library called `pubsuber` for accessing google pubsub.
For more information look [here](https://github.com/sandvikcode/pubsuber).