# Deadlock inside gRPC Read() function

Tags: c++, deadlock, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a C++ project, which uses Google Pub/Sub.

As there is no native support for Google Pub/Sub in C++, I am using it through gRPC. Thus, I have generated corresponding pubsub.grpc.pb.h, pubsub.grpc.pb.cc, pubsub.pb.h and pubsub.pb.cc files via protoc.

I wrote a lightweight wrapper-class, for subscription management. Class basically creates a new thread and starts listening for new messages. Here is the code example (code was built based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260017/consumer-example-for-google-pub-sub-in-c) question):

```
class Consumer 
{
public:
    Consumer();
    ~Consumer();
    void startConsume();
// ...
    std::string m_subscriptionName;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;
    std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> m_channel;
    std::unique_ptr<google::pubsub::v1::Subscriber::Stub> m_stub;
    std::atomic<bool> m_runThread;
};

Consumer::Consumer()
{
    m_channel = grpc::CreateChannel("pubsub.googleapis.com:443", grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials());
    m_stub = google::pubsub::v1::Subscriber::NewStub(m_channel);
    m_subscriptionName = "something";
}

Consumer::~Consumer()
{
    m_runThread = false;
    if (m_thread && m_thread->joinable())
    {
        m_thread->join();
    }
}

void Consumer::startConsume()
{
    m_thread.reset(new std::thread([this]()
    {
        m_runThread = true;
        while (m_runThread)
        {
            grpc::ClientContext context;
            std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientReaderWriter<google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest, 
                                                     google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullResponse>> stream(m_stub->StreamingPull(&context));
            // send the initial message
            google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest req;
            req.set_subscription(m_subscriptionName);
            req.set_stream_ack_deadline_seconds(10);

            // if write passed successfully, start subscription
            if (!stream->Write(req))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // receive messages
            google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullResponse response;
            while (stream->Read(&response))
            {
                google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest ack_request;
                for (const auto& message : response.received_messages())
                {
                    // process messages ...
                    ack_request.add_ack_ids(message.ack_id());
                }
                stream->Write(ack_request);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Several instances of the `Consumer` class are created within a process.

It seems works fine. However sometimes program stucks on `stream->Read(&response)`code. Debugging showed that thread was stuck inside of `Read()` function call - the stream does not read anything and does not exit from function either, despite that Pub/Sub buffer is not empty. After restarting the application, all messages are successfully read. It seems like a deadlock inside of `Read()`.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? What can cause this behavior?

Comment: This calls for a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated the question. However, for reproducibility `pubsub.grpc.pb.h`, `pubsub.grpc.pb.cc`, `pubsub.pb.h` and `pubsub.pb.cc` generated files are also needed.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please, consider all the implications of "reproducible" and "minimal". You provided an extract of your code, but you have to create an example.

Comment: If you do copy-past into a code editor, of course it would not compile. It has dependencies on `gRPC` library and also above mentioned files, which have been generated using protoc. Aside from that, compilation would not help in investigation, as it requires GCP environment with valid Pub/Sub topic(s) for both publishing and subscribing... or may be I should have included that as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  The only thing that jumps at me is no calls to `stream->Finish()` when the `Write()` or `Read()` calls fail.

Comment: @coryan thanks for the comment. As far as I remember. I fixed it by adding some missing components, which also included your suggestion. Apart from that, there was something related to timeout, which was needed to specify as well.