# Google Cloud Pubsub Async Streaming API in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to find a documentation on using Pubsub Streaming API over async grpc but can't find any.

I have this simple code to read all messages from topic:

```
  auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
  auto stub = std::make_unique<Subscriber::Stub>(
        grpc::CreateChannel("pubsub.googleapis.com", creds));

  ClientContext context;
  std::unique_ptr<ClientReaderWriter<
      StreamingPullRequest, StreamingPullResponse>> stream(
          stub->StreamingPull(&context));

  StreamingPullRequest request;
  request.set_subscription(
      "projects/test/subscriptions/test-subscription");
  request.set_stream_ack_deadline_seconds(10);
  stream->Write(request);

  StreamingPullResponse response;
  while (stream->Read(&response)) {
    StreamingPullRequest ack_request;
    for (const auto &message : response.received_messages()) {
      ack_request.add_ack_ids(message.ack_id());
    }
    stream->Write(ack_request);
  }
```

Basically I wanna do the same but with async rpc call so this code is called inside of callback:

```
    StreamingPullRequest ack_request;
    for (const auto &message : response.received_messages()) {
      ack_request.add_ack_ids(message.ack_id());
    }
    stream->Write(ack_request);
```

Could you help me with a simple example of async code doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Currently *Google Cloud Platform C++* [Pub/Sub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/master/google/cloud/pubsub) library has not yet being officially announced by the vendor and there are no ETAs for the implementation, thus the code base exists as a proof of concept and still not fully documented with no decent examples of usage. You can keep track the community efforts for further library development following [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/777) Github thread.

As far as I see you're looking for any of insights performing [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull) via async [gRPC](https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/) call, reviewing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292005/9928809) being posted by @Manuel Menzella I would recommend to check out his approach that can be conceptually suitable for your use case.