# C++ example code of receiving data from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to find a C++ example of receiving data via Google's "cloud" via Google's Pub/Sub.

Here it seems that C++ isn't supported:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/777

and again here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62573062/997112

But on the main Github page:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp

It says the languages are 90.5% C++.

Can anyone help/is it possible to receive data from the Google Cloud in C++?

Comment: It says that "pub/sub" isn't supported - *other* features of the library are supported in C++

Comment: @SuperStormer to account for the 90.5%?

Comment: [The link says it has been GA'ed in 2020Q4](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/pubsub/quickstart/README.md)

Comment: At the base level, Pub/Sub just calls an HTTP endpoint with a JSON payload. This is very easy to process in C and C++. An SDK is not required and in many cases just adds complexity and bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Pub/Sub client library in C++ recently became available. Code samples in the Pub/Sub documentation should all have C++ examples, for example, [publishing messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#c++) and [receiving messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#c++).